# Contact box is inoperable while in "mobile" size resolution. HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

There is no custom css set for smaller resolutions. I am having a problem where if I load the webpage at a low enough resolution, click the contact box, I cannot enter any fields till I stretch the browser to a larger resolution. At this point I can edit the contact box and also go back to the mobile resolution and have it still be operable.

The only way to truly explain this would be for you guys to go to the temporary site I setup [here](http://johnzadroga.com). I have scanned the HTML code to see if I am missing a closed div or something, but this scenario is very odd to me, especially since it works at a full resolution.

Please let me know what I am missing, I have exercised all of the possibilities.

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your web site. Include an example in your question. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Sorry about that. I just felt that it wouldn't make sense to copy and paste excerpts. I completely understand where you are coming from and will make sure to provide examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the `z-index` of either the pop-up or the background/overlay that comes up with it. I pulled up the dev tools and set a high z-index on the pop-up and a low index on the overlay and that fixed it. However, the elements are reset each time you open the pop-up. That makes me think that the elements are generated each time rather than shown/hidden. Whatever the situation is, you'll need to add an appropriate `z-index` to either the css or the element's themselves (inline - not recommended) and possibly with an `!important` depending on what all is going on in the code.

Comment: It was weird, because the z-indexes were setup correctly. I had to make the change more drastic. Thanks for the help.